# How to order result but not selected row using sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION, ORG.EXTERNALKEY
FROM organization org
WHERE org.ownerid = (SELECT id
                      FROM organization
                     WHERE externalkey = '970000')
     OR org.externalkey = '970000'
ORDER BY org.description;
```

This is my sql query. I used "ORDER BY org.description". But this is not my requirement exactly. I want to make the first (org.externalkey='970000') in result of the query. Rows will be ordered (but org.externalkey='970000' row will be the first). How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

You just need to add a CASE statement in the ORDER BY CLAUSE

```
 ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN externalkey = '970000' THEN 0 else 1 END,
           org.description
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION, ORG.EXTERNALKEY
FROM organization org
WHERE org.ownerid = (SELECT id
                      FROM organization
                     WHERE externalkey = '970000')
     OR org.externalkey = '970000'
ORDER BY org.externalkey ,org.description;
```